# Are the proportions of a Christian cross based on a golden ratio?

Tags: religion, mathematics

I was just 3D modeling something and I noticed the intersection of two lines I made   by multiplying one by the golden ratio looks exactly like the kind of cross I see on top of or in the window of a church.

Did whoever made that symbol base it off of the golden ratio, maybe dating back to the Romans? I suspect that since the golden ratio appears in the human body that the cross could have inadvertently inherited that ratio by being used to crucify people.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: In addition to the Wikipedia page on the [Christian cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_cross), there is also an interesting Wikipedia page on [Christian cross variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_cross_variants) which you might find helpful.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no rule for Christian crosses - they come in all shapes and sizes.  The golden ratio is aesthetically pleasing and I wouldn't be surprised if many crosses took advantage of it.  But there is no police who will arrest you for creating a cross with a different ratio.  I also sincerely doubt that the crosses used to crucify people were aesthetic, or that the crosses on cathedrals were used to crucify people.   I think this is just an aesthetic observation.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I wrote. I never claimed the crucifix used to crucify people was designed for aesthetic purposes, that's flat out ridiculous. What I said explicitly is that because the golden ratio occurs in the human body that the crucifix might have been designed with a similar ratio itself, strictly because it was designed to crucify people. As far as I know, this dates back to the Romans who sometimes crucified people and in doing so eventually gave birth to Christianity. That's all research I did about the history of the cross prior to asking.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: Re the golden ratio being aesthetically pleasing, I wouldn't be surprised if the causality is reversed.  That is, instead of intentionally using the golden ratio to design crosses, people tried to depict crosses in an asthetically pleasing way, which wound up being close to the golden ratio.

Comment: @Vane Voe: The Romans did not "sometimes" crucify people, they did it quite often.  E.g. 6000 recaptured slaves after the Spartacus Rebellion.  Nor would the conventional Christian cross be suitable for execution, as it would allow the crucified person's feet to reach the ground.  You'd want a rather taller post...

Comment: *quite often* is subjective without any concise data on what the consensus of the historical community considers to be "quite often". 6000 compared to what percentage of the accessible population? I don't know that any geometric argument has been provided to show that a person's feet must necesserily reach the ground for such a crucifix.

Comment: I agree with Mark C. Wallace. I doubt the Romans were terribly concerned with the dimensions of the crosses they used for crucifixion. Also the cross has little to do with the dimensions of the body given that the head is not as long as the arms but the upper three arms of a cross are usually the same length

Comment: See [sacred geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_geometry).

Answer (score 3):

Your question assumes the old myth that the golden ratio appears in the human body. There is no factual basis about that. I suggest that you read [Keith Devlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Devlin)'s *[The Myth That Will Not Go Away](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_05_07.html)*.

In particular, the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: That's not quite correct because Fibonacci's sequence occurs in the human body. You can observe that easily looking at the ratios of the segments of bones in fingers, hands, wrist, arm, etc. The golden ratio is a specific limiting case of that sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The Christian crucifix is based on the device the Romans (and others) used to execute humans by crucifixion (hence the name).
This device is of necessity shaped such as to fit a human body.

The golden ratio is also based on the dimensions of a human body.

So the relation is there, but it's indirect because both factors depend on a common third.